# struts2 adding select tag column in table

Tags: struts2

i am trying add and remove rows dynamically and select tag at one column in table but its not working

Javascript

```
    function addRowDynamically()
{
        rowCount++;
        $(itemDetails).append("<div><div> <div><s:select label="search engine"                                              headerKey="-1" headerValue="Engines"                                              list="itemlist"                                               name="itemName" /></div> </div> <div> <div id='product_details'> <input type='text' name='product_details[]' /> </div> </div></div>");                
                reCalcRow();
 }
```

and jsp file

```
        $(itemDetails).append("<div><div> <div><s:select label="search engine" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Engines" list="itemlist" name="itemName" /></div> </div> <div> <div id='product_details'> <input type='text' name='product_details[]' /> </div> </div></div>
```

problem is select tag in javascript is not working

Comment: Do you have errors in the console?

Comment: Are you trying `s:select` inside an java script function?

Comment: This will not work without ajax call, Struts tags are rendered at server.